# Travelling from London to Paris and return journey

Tags: london, paris, aircraft, high-speed-rail

[London to Paris](https://www.google.com/search?q=london%20to%20paris&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&prmd=minv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKxp7Bj-v2AhVMZd4KHbVbDLUQ_AUoAnoECAIQAg&biw=360&bih=674&dpr=2)

[Eurostar - London to Paris](https://youtu.be/l5RAYy9Uymc)

What would be the better choice for travelling between London and Paris return journey in terms of cost, travelling time if a comparison is made between selecting airline and rail route?

Rail route - Eurostar

Travel distance between London and Paris by plane.

Travel distance between London and Paris by Eurostar.

Comment: What has your own research so far shown?

Comment: Both are perfectly reasonable choices for many people. Only you can answer which is the better choice for you - we don't know the relative importance you place on cost vs. time.

Comment: It may depend on where in Paris and London you depart from/need to get to. But unless those are close to airports the balance is highly skewed in favour of the train IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no unique answer to this question, it depends a lot on the exact points of origin and destination, and possibly other parameters.

But if you start from central Paris and need to go to central London, then it's most likely a lot faster and cheaper to take the train: to fly, you'll have to get to and from the airports, which in most cases adds significant time and cost (especially in the case of some of the London airports). The exception is London City Airport (LCY), but flights there are often quite a bit more expensive.

Also, when you use the train, passport checks are included in the check-in procedure, while when flying you have to go through those once you land. If you have large bags, you'll also have to wait for them to be delivered when flying. On the other hand, you don't have to carry those on board yourself when you fly.

Talking about luggage, don't forget that nowadays the cheapest airline fares do not include check-in luggage and may have extremely low limits on hand luggage if you don't pay extra. None of that applies when you take the train.

Trains are also less subject to disruption due to weather or other factors (but definitely not immune!).

Finally, taking the train is a lot more environmentally friendly.

I've travelled between Paris and London dozens of times, and I don't think I've ever flown.

Answer (score 1):

For short distance like London/Paris, Train will always be more efficient in terms of cost and time; even if the actual time on the train will be longer than the actual time on the plane.

The main issue is that airports are far from city centers; getting to/from the airport costs time and money.

Comment: "Train will always be more efficient in terms of cost and time" It's not as black and white as that. Budget airlines can often be cheaper than trains, even accounting for the cost of a train or bus from/to the city at each end. Whether it's worth the additional hassle is a personal choice, of course.

Comment: When I took Eurostar from London to Paris, I had to book 2 months ahead to get a decent price.